# How to center three span3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'm trying to create a grid with centered rows of three span3 divs.

I have tried to achieve this by wrapping the three span3s in a centered span9, but that doesn't seem to work.

My problem is that the divs don't center correctly and as I'm new to HTML and CSS I would really need some help. Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span9 center">
       <div class="span3">
          <p>THUMBNAIL1</p>
       </div> 
       <div class="span3">
          <p>THUMBNAIL2</p>
       </div>     
       <div class="span3">
          <p>THUMBNAIL3</p>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

etc.

CSS:

```
.center {
     float: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     align: center;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstarp version 2.3?

Comment: As a note `align:center;` doesn't exist. The right syntax is `text-align:center;`

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v2.3.2

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
align: center;
```

Use:

```
text-align: center;
```

`align` is not a css rule though I guess that you got it from the syntax of `align` as an attribute on the tag

You could also put them inside and element with position relative and then inside have them with:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: (0, 50%);
```

You can also use this:

```
.span3 {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
.span9 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/FH6kc/)

Comment: If there was any way I could use partial offset, e.g "span3 offset1.5", I suppose that would also solve the problem. What do you think about this?

Comment: I will update answer with how to do it with position absolute